Telerik Reporting ```MissingMethodException'```on AWS Lambda with .NET 8 (arm64)
I'm deploying a .NET 8 application with Telerik Reporting to AWS Lambda using the public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:8-arm64 base image. The application builds and publishes without any issues, but when the Lambda function runs, it fails with the following error
System.MissingMethodException: Type: Telerik.Reporting.ReportSerialization.Current.ReportSerializable`1[Telerik.Reporting.Report]
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.CreateInstance(Type type, String name)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.ReadObject(Type type)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.ReadXmlElement(String name)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.Deserialize(IResourceHandler handler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.XmlSerializerBase.Deserialize(XmlReader reader, IResourceHandler resourceHandler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream, IResourceHandler resourceHandler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.ReportPackager.UnpackageDocument(Stream packageStream)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.UriReportDocumentResolver.Resolve(IProcessingContext context, UriReportSource rs)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportDocumentResolver`1.Telerik.Reporting.Processing.IReportDocumentResolver.Resolve(IProcessingContext context, ReportSource rs)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportDocumentResolver.Resolve(IProcessingContext context, ReportSource source)

My Dockerfile:
# Base runtime image for AWS Lambda with .NET 8 (arm64)
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:8-arm64 AS base

# Build stage with .NET SDK for arm64
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG NUGET_USERNAME=''
ARG NUGET_PASSWORD=''
ARG VERSION=0.0.0-dev
ARG PROJECT_DIR=my-project
ARG ADD_DEV_SOURCES=off
ENV ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME=${NUGET_USERNAME}
ENV ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=${NUGET_PASSWORD}

WORKDIR /build
COPY Reports.Lambda/NuGet.Config .
COPY Reports.Lambda/*.csproj Reports.Lambda/
COPY Reports.Engine/*.csproj Reports.Engine/
WORKDIR /build/Reports.Lambda
RUN dotnet restore --packages /src/nuget_packages -v n

WORKDIR /build
COPY Reports.Lambda/ Reports.Lambda/
COPY Reports.Engine/ Reports.Engine/
COPY ${PROJECT_DIR}/Server/Reports/ Reports.Lambda/Server/Reports/
WORKDIR /build/Reports.Lambda
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -p:Version=${VERSION}
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -p:Version=${VERSION} -o /app/publish
COPY ${PROJECT_DIR}/Server/Reports /app/publish/Server/Reports

FROM base AS final
RUN dnf update -y
RUN dnf install -y fontconfig libicu
COPY fonts /var/task/fonts
COPY Reports.Lambda/font-config-local.conf /etc/fonts/local.conf
RUN fc-cache -svf
WORKDIR /var/task
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=0
COPY --from=build /app/publish/ .
CMD ["Reports.Lambda::Reports.Lambda.Function::FunctionHandlerAsync"]

Steps I've Taken:
Installed necessary libraries (fontconfig, libicu).
Copied custom fonts and rebuilt the font cache using fc-cache.
Configured DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=0 for full globalization support.
Questions:
What could be causing the MissingMethodException in the AWS Lambda environment?
Is there a compatibility issue between Telerik Reporting, .NET 8, and the AWS Lambda runtime?
How can I ensure all Telerik Reporting dependencies are correctly included in the Lambda deployment?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
